# What is the term for a relation whose inverse relation is serial?

Tags: terminology, relations

A relation $R$ is serial iff $\forall x, \exists y, xRy$. What is the name of the inverse property stating that $\forall y, \exists x, xRy$? And is there a name for the property which is the conjunction of both previous ones?

Comment: It is simply called the inverse. It may or may not exist.

Comment: I don't understand: the inverse of a binary relation always exists.

Comment: Not an explicit function for it. Take $y = x^{1/2}, x = -4$.

Comment: @Joseph I edited it again because I really think that's what you're asking, and I don't want people to be deterred by a strange title. I left the body of the post alone.

Comment: @Jossie Functions are a special kind of relations whose inverse is not necessary a function.

Answer (score 1):

According to Proof wiki, the first thing you are asking about ($\forall y\exists x(xRy)$) can be called a [**right total relation**](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition%3aRight-Total_Relation), and the thing you defined as "serial relation" may be called a **left total relation.**

They mention that a right-and-left total relation may be called a **total relation** on the [left total relation page](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition%3aLeft-Total_Relation), but caution you not to confuse it with a "connected relation."